# Haskell Polymorphic Tree Sum

Tags: haskell, tree, functional-programming, sum, polymorphism

I wrote the following code for handling a polymorphic binary tree in Haskell as a preperation for the functional programming exam next week:

```
data ITree t = Leaf | Node t (ITree t) (ITree t) 
             deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

treeSum :: ITree t -> Int
treeSum Leaf = 0
treeSum (Node n t1 t2) = n + (treeSum t1) + (treeSum t2)
```

Now I have the problem, that the code doesn't compile:

```
...\tree.hs:8:26:
Couldn't match type `t' with `Int'
  `t' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for treeSum :: ITree t -> Int
      at ...\tree.hs:7:1
In the first argument of `(+)', namely `n'
In the first argument of `(+)', namely `n + (treeSum t1)'
In the expression: n + (treeSum t1) + (treeSum t2)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
Prelude>
```

Do you know what's wrong with treeSum? I think it has something to do with the polymorphic type of ITree, but I don't know how to solve this. Do I have to specify that the type t must be a type which can be counted/enumerated? Probably with a class instance of such a type class?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Simon

Comment: What should `treeSum (Node "marshmellow" Leaf Leaf)` be?

Comment: There's no need for that :) But for Floats!

Comment: Right, but the type you give for `treeSum` promises it works for any type `t`, even `String`.

Comment: Just remove the type signature for `treeSum` and then ask the compiler what the type is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The compiler can't verify that the outcome will be an `Int`.  As it stands, you could call `treeSum` with an `ITree Integer` argument (and the operations wouldn't produce an `Int`).

Try changing the signature to `treeSum :: Integral t => ITree t -> t`.

Comment: Thank you, this solved the problem? What does Integral t say? Is it a type class or a conversion/typecasting?

Comment: `treeSum :: Num t => ITree t -> t` would be better: it only uses `fromInteger`and `(+)`.

Comment: @saimn It's a constraint that says `t` must be a type that implements the `Integral` typeclass.